# Separate an email address into its username and domain name

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, strings, parsing

This is my first ever Python program and I wanted to get everyone's opinions on it. The goal of the program is to separate an email address into its username and domain name.

```
import sys
import getopt

argv = sys.argv[1:]

# -------Error Handling-Start----------
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "l:s:h", ["list ", "single ", "help "])
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print(f"{err}\n""\n"
          "Usage: <Options> <Input> \n"
          "-l, --list        Specify a list of emails to be sliced \n"
          "-s, --single      Specify a single email to be sliced \n"
          "-h, --help        Show options")
    opts = []
# -------Error Handling-End------------

for opt, file_arg in opts:
    if opt in ['-h', '--help']:
        sys.exit("Usage: <Options> <Input> \n"
                 "-l, --list        Specify a list of emails to be sliced \n"
                 "-s, --single      Specify a single email to be sliced \n"
                 "-h, --help        Show options")
# If option -h is present, display MAN page

for opt, email_arg in opts:
    if opt in ['-s', '--single']:
        email = email_arg
        username = email[:email.index('@')]
        domain = email[email.index('@') + 1:]
        print(f"Your username: {username}")
        print(f"Your domain name: {domain}\n")
# If option -s is present, split input email into username and domain then print the output

for opt, file_arg in opts:
    if opt in ['-l', '--list']:
        file = file_arg

        email_file = open(file, "r")

        for string in email_file:
            username = string[:string.index('@')]
            domain = string[string.index('@') + 1:]
            print(f"Your username: {username}")
            print(f"Your domain name: {domain}")
# If option -l is present read file specified then loop through each line while splitting each into username and domain

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.exit("Usage: <Options> <Input> \n"
             "-l, --list        Specify a list of emails to be sliced \n"
             "-s, --single      Specify a single email to be sliced \n"
             "-h, --help        Show options")
# If only one argument is supplied, print MAN page.
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/256774/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The general style looks good. The biggest opportunity for improvement is your use of `getopt`. You should use the newer and easier [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) instead. Most of your code is used to parse and use the command line arguments. All of that can be done in three lines with [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

```py
import argparse

arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", dest="file", default=False, action="store_true")
arg_parser.add_argument("input", type=str)
args = arg_parser.parse_args()
```

Instead of using `--single` or `--list`, I added a single flag `--file` (or `-f`), as the former choice is not only ambiguous (what happens if you specify neither or both?) as well as potentially misleading in their name.
A help option with "-h" is introduced automatically.

`"-f", "--file"` are the flags you can use to specify this argument. `dest=file` means that the created object `args` wil have an attribute `args.file` that stores the resulting value. `action="store_true"` means that the flag has to be specified without a value (i.e. `-f` instead of `-f True`) to set it.

After that, you can access your inputs as a strings (because `type=str`) by `args.input` (because the first argument to `add_argument` was `"input"`).

`open` of a file should always be paired with a `close` when you are done using it, as is also true for other I/O objects such as network connections. Instead of manually calling `close`, one should prefer to use Python's context managers with the `with` keyword, which automatically perform any cleanup.

```py
if args.file:
    with open(args.input, "r") as file:
        emails = file.readlines()
else:
    emails = [args.input]
```

Your code to split the email into username and domain can be done with `str.split`, assuming that there is exactly one "@". If there are not "@" or more than one, you should probably notify the user that there is an error anyway. If you want to have actual "serious" code that goes into production in a live system, see Toby Speight's comment on pointers how to properly do that.

```py
    if email.count("@") != 1:
        ...  # Notify the user
    username, domain = email.split("@")
    print(f"Your username: {username}")
    print(f"Your domain name: {domain}")
```

Finally, your use of `sys.exit` is incorrect. You should only use `sys.exit(n)` with an integer `n`. `sys.exit(0)` means "successful", anything else means "failed". Unless you have specific needs, `sys.exit(1)` is the default choice for failure.

To give user friendly error messages, the easiest way is to use `print`. You can show the messages as an error by specifying `file=sys.stderr` (as opposed to the default `file=sys.stdout`).

```py
        print(f"{email} is not a valid email.", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

In total, this is what I'd propose your program could look like:

```py
import sys
import argparse

arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", dest="file", default=False, action="store_true")
arg_parser.add_argument("input", type=str)
args = arg_parser.parse_args()

if args.file:
    with open(args.input, "r") as file:
        emails = file.readlines()
else:
    emails = [args.input]

for email in emails:
    if email.count("@") != 1:
        print(f"{email} is not a valid email.", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
    username, domain = email.split("@")
    print(f"Your username: {username}")
    print(f"Your domain name: {domain}")
```

Comment: I'd have to look up the relevant RFC (5322, these days?) to see if `@` is allowed in the local part.  If so, we'll want to find the _last_ `@` to identify the domain.  There's far to much broken email-handling code around (I frequently encounter systems that think they are allowed to change the case of the local part!) that I wouldn't want to encourage more implementation by those who can't or won't read the RFC.

Comment: I think you misread the code - `--single` seems to be accepting arguments, and `--list` means _read from file_.  I think they could helpfully be renamed, as your interpretation shows!

Comment: @TobySpeight You're completely right regarding the arguments. I'll update my answer to show the correct behavior. Regarding RFC5322, you are right as well. Although I think this should be more of a note "If you actually want a serious and safe system, don't try to implement an email parser yourself". Going into detail I feel would exceed the scope of a review on this level.

Answer (score 0):

This works for toto@domain.com and also with toto@tutu@domain.com which is an RFC compliant email address.

```
def splitMail(mail: str):
    parts  = mail.rsplit('@', 1)
    user   = parts[0]
    domain = parts[1]
    
    return user, domain
```

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if it showed that the original code did not support @ symbols in the user ID part and provided a citation for the claim that they were RFC-compliant.  It would be even stronger if there was a citation that showed that any email addresses actually use more than one @ symbol.  You also might consider explaining the other choices that you made.  E.g. why you assigned the two parts to variables rather than just returning them.